# Laravel notification showing "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token" when integrated with FCM

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging, laravel-notification

I have integrated FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) notification with my laravel project.
I have added the method `routeNotificationForFcm` in the `User` model.
The notification system is working fine when the firebase device token is specified directly in the method, but not working when the token is accessed from database.

The working code added is given below.

```
public function routeNotificationForFcm()
{
    return ['dJQqgKlETpqCB3uxHtfUbL:APA91bFdrcXZMNH0iMjkXMoop_b_nI3xF92DU0P1nrHVQsTDK4w-OH5QR6BsnWIV-wSxSV7avzuBmLVizNyrRcKfAQz6H66JEP9rWKUeIi7m7wEZwRiuW_WdCW_LaZajdFZlxfCUonCL'];
}
```

The code that is not working is as follows (database query)

```
public function routeNotificationForFcm()
{
    return $this->from('fcm_tokens')->where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('device_token');
}
```

The error message showing is **The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token**

Comment: I had checked the query result logs and there is no problem with the query.

Comment: can you try     return $this->from('fcm_tokens')->where('user_id', $user->id)->value('device_token');

Comment: @Xun What's the issue when using pluck method?

Comment: Pluck method will return you instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection , which is not the value you want , so using ->value('device_token') instead of ->pluck('device_token) should be is what you need

Comment: @Affar how did to manage/generate the tokens? sorry stupid question.

Comment: The token usually gets generated for the first time whenever the app is first installed. You have to send the generated token to your back-end server and save it there to send notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck) `pluck` return `Collection` - so you just need to call `toArray()` after you called `pluck` on query/collection to return `array`, as you did previously with mocked token.

```
public function routeNotificationForFcm()
{
    return $this->from('fcm_tokens')->where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('device_token')->toArray();
}
```

Also you call for `$user->id` but you doesn't have one in this scope.
Solution is simple you need to pass the value or take it from `$this`.

```
public function routeNotificationForFcm()
{
    return $this->from('fcm_tokens')->where('user_id', $this->id)->pluck('device_token')->toArray();
}
```

But personally I'll recommend you to define separate relation for that

```
public function fcmTokens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FcmToken::class);
}
```

`FcmToken` - is just guess how you named your model.
And then you can reuse it like this to return `array` of related tokens for specific `User` model

```
public function routeNotificationForFcm()
{
    return $this->fcmTokens()->pluck('device_token')->toArray();
}
```

In the end, if you structure your code like this you would have general relation and make with this relation you code more flexible.